# Slow loop in VBA after first execution, fast again if I use "STOP"

Tags: vba, loops

I have this code in vba using Project 2019 which goes through selected resources and creates a task which is then deleted.

What happens is that the first run in the loop goes much faster than the next ones. The only way the speed is mantained constant is if I introduce an "STOP" before the loop is finished.

EDIT: I mean that if I use STOP at the end of the loop and then resume it manually (and do this until all loops are finished), it is much faster than if the loop is run on its own.

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub create1personFAM_SIM_imp()
    Dim ntask  As task
    Dim ntaskre As task
    Dim selectres As Resources
    Dim re     As Resource
    Dim k      As Long
    Dim gap_found As Long
    Dim found1stFAM As Long
    Dim assigg As Assignment
    Dim ko     As Boolean
    Dim end_split As Date
    Dim start_split As Date
    Dim startgap As Date
    Dim endgap As Date
    Dim Startsearching As Date
    Dim EndSearching As Date
    Dim diasgapmax As Long
    Dim fam_min As Long
    Dim wbXL   As Excel.Application
    Set wbXL = Nothing
    Set wbXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim start_split_prev As Date
    Dim k_hueco As Long
    Dim k_excess As Long
    Dim excess_splitted As Double
    Dim gap_before As Long
    Dim gap_after As Long
    Dim First_gap As Long
    Dim Obj_duration As Long
    Dim nametask As String
    
    
    diasgapmax = 0
    
    fam_min = 0
    Obj_duration = 20
    First_gap = 0
    nametask = "FAM_AIT_"
    'nametask = "Simulation Exercises_"
    
    Startsearching = "6/9/2021"
    EndSearching = "6/4/2022"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    Set selectres = ActiveSelection.Resources
    
    ViewApplyEx BuiltInView:=pjViewGantt, ApplyTo:=0
    
    For Each re In selectres
        k = 0
        If Not re Is Nothing Then
            'If InStr(re.Name, "C1_EN-5") > 0 Or InStr(re.Name, "C1_OF-5") > 0 Then
            
            ActiveProject.Tasks.Add re.Name
            Set ntask = ActiveProject.Tasks(ActiveProject.Tasks.Count)
            ntask.duration = 8 * 60
            ntask.Calendar = "TRAINING1"          'Application.GlobalBaseCalendars(1)
            ntask.Start = Startsearching
            
            ntask.Assignments.Add ResourceID:=re.ID, Units:=1
            
            For Each assigg In ntask.Assignments
                assigg.Units = 1
            Next assigg
            
            
            ActiveProject.Tasks.Add nametask & re.Name
            Set ntaskre = ActiveProject.Tasks(ActiveProject.Tasks.Count)
            ntaskre.duration = 8 * 60 * Obj_duration
            ntaskre.Calendar = "TRAINING1"        'Application.GlobalBaseCalendars(1)
            
            'If First_gap = 0 Then
                found1stFAM = 0
            'Else
            '    found1stFAM = 1
            'End If
            
            gap_found = 0
            
            ko = True
            While ko = True And k <= Obj_duration
                
                Debug.Print re.Name & " " & ntask.Start
                
                If ntask.StartDriver.OverAllocatedAssignments(pjOverallocationTypeWorkingOnOtherTasks).Count = 0 Then
                    
                    k_hueco = k_hueco + 1
                    If gap_found = 1 Then
                        endgap = ntask.Finish
                    Else
                        startgap = ntask.Start
                        endgap = ntask.Finish
                        gap_found = 1
                    End If
                    
                Else
                    
                    If gap_found = 1 Then
                        If k_hueco >= fam_min Then
                            k_excess = k_hueco - fam_min
                            excess_splitted = CDbl(k_excess) / 2
                            If excess_splitted > diasgapmax Then
                                gap_before = diasgapmax
                                gap_after = diasgapmax
                            Else
                                gap_before = wbXL.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(excess_splitted, 0)
                                gap_after = wbXL.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(excess_splitted, 0)
                            End If
                            
                            end_split = Application.DateAdd(startgap, gap_before * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                            If found1stFAM = 0 Then
                                start_split = Application.DateSubtract(endgap, diasgapmax * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                            Else
                                start_split = Application.DateSubtract(endgap, gap_before * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                            End If
                            
                            k = k + k_hueco - gap_before - gap_after
                            
                            If k_hueco > fam_min + diasgapmax Then
                                end_split = Application.DateAdd(startgap, diasgapmax * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                            End If
                            
                            If found1stFAM = 0 Then
                                k = k + gap_before
                                ntaskre.Start = Application.DateAdd(startgap, First_gap * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                                found1stFAM = 1
                            Else
                                ntaskre.Split start_split_prev, end_split
                            End If
                            
                            start_split_prev = start_split
                            
                            
                        Else
                            
                        End If
                    End If
                    
                    k_hueco = 0
                    gap_found = 0
                    
                    
                    
                End If
                
                ntask.Start = Application.DateAdd(ntask.Start, 8 * 60, ntask.CalendarObject)
                ko = ntask.Finish <= CDate(EndSearching & " 18:00")
            Wend
            
            
            If gap_found = 1 Then
                If k_hueco >= fam_min Then
                    k_excess = k_hueco - fam_min
                    excess_splitted = CDbl(k_excess) / 2
                    If excess_splitted > diasgapmax Then
                        gap_before = diasgapmax
                        gap_after = diasgapmax
                    Else
                        gap_before = wbXL.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(excess_splitted, 0)
                        gap_after = wbXL.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(excess_splitted, 0)
                    End If
                    
                    end_split = Application.DateAdd(startgap, gap_before * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                    
                    If found1stFAM = 0 Then
                        start_split = Application.DateSubtract(endgap, diasgapmax * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                    Else
                        start_split = Application.DateSubtract(endgap, gap_before * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                    End If
                    
                    k = k + k_hueco - gap_before - gap_after
                    
                    If k_hueco > fam_min + diasgapmax Then
                        end_split = Application.DateAdd(startgap, diasgapmax * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                    End If
                    
                    If found1stFAM = 0 Then
                        k = k + gap_before
                        ntaskre.Start = Application.DateAdd(startgap, First_gap * 8 * 60, ntaskre.CalendarObject)
                        found1stFAM = 1
                    Else
                        ntaskre.Split start_split_prev, end_split
                    End If
                    
                    start_split_prev = start_split
                    
                    
                Else
                    
                End If
            End If
            
            
            ntask.Delete
            ntaskre.Assignments.Add ResourceID:=re.ID, Units:=1
            Set ntask = Nothing
            Set ntaskre = Nothing
            Stop
            ' End If
        End If
    Next re
    
    Set wbXL = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox (Time)
End Sub
```

Do you have any ideas for not needing the "STOP" and getting a constant speed?

Thanks!

Comment: `Stop` stops the loop. So the loop is only executed partially. No wonder it is faster.

Comment: I mean that if I stop at the end of the loop and then resume it manually (until all loops are finished), it is faster than if the loop is run on its own.